# Flow doesn't complain about incorrect type

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux, flowtype, nuclide-editor

In this piece of code, flow is not complaining about the value `dog` being set on the state. It seems to be ignoring the `NamespaceData` definition. I've set up the types so it should complain. I'm running on nuclide and flow is working properly for everything else.

All of the properties of `action` such as `namespace`, `project`, `collection` are strings.

```
// @flow

import { NAMESPACE_SET } from '../actions/NamespaceActions'

type NamespaceData = {
  project: string,
  collection: string,
}

type NamespaceState = {
  [namespace: string]: NamespaceData,
}
const initialState: NamespaceState = {}

function namespaceReducer(state: NamespaceState = initialState, action: Object): NamespaceState {
  switch (action) {
    case NAMESPACE_SET: {
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.namespace]: {
          project: action.project,
          collection: action.collection,
          dog: 1,
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return state
}

export default namespaceReducer
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Flow is not strict about unknown properties in objects by default, e.g.

```
// @flow

type Thing = {
  known: string;
};

var obj: Thing = {
  known: 'hi',
  unknown: 4,
};
```

typechecks fine even though `unknown` is not in the type.

Flow [0.32](https://github.com/facebook/flow/releases/tag/v0.32.0) includes

- New syntax for exact object types: use {| and |} instead of { and }. Where {x: string} contains at least the property x, {| x: string |} contains ONLY the property x.

In your example you'd want exact object syntax with:

```
type NamespaceData = {|
  project: string,
  collection: string,
|};
```

Comment: Ah, awesome. Thank you. I was reading the quick reference docs rather than the reference!